# should we forcefully unload a model loaded via loadModel()

Tags: cakephp

Is there a function like unloadModel in cakePHP that should be called to unload a model that was loaded using loadModel() function?

I found an unload method,

http://api20.cakephp.org/file/Cake/Model/BehaviorCollection.php#method-BehaviorCollectionunload

But it seems to be used for Behavior. Im new to cake. Is there a function like that or does it get automatically unloaded when the called action loses scope?

One more doubt; is using loadModel against MVC's normal conventions? Does it have any adverse effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to unload your model.  If you're going to use the model throughout the entire Controller, then use the `$uses` variable:

```
public $uses = array('MyModel', 'AnotherModel');
```

If you're going to just use it in a specific action(s), use `loadModel`:

```
$this->loadModel('MyModel');
```

That's it - no unloading necessary.

And no, it's not against MVC imo and I have seen no adverse effects.

It's VERY common to load a model.  Example - most of my projects require a few "homepages" that have greatly-varying data from nearly ever model.  In that case, I create a "DashboardsController", which doesn't even have a table - then I load each model when I need to access it's data.  (Or with `$uses` if I'm going to use it's data in all the actions).

Comment: special thanks for that DashboardsController idea. If it wasnt for that, my next post would have been on creating dashboard with data from all models! ;)

Comment: nice!  glad it helped.  I think I've asked that same question on here about a year ago :)

Answer (score 1):

no, behaviors and models are two different things.

behaviors add functionality through hooks. Meaning: they alter the way other methods in models work. So if you want to geocode your data automatically, you use a geocoder behavior. Or if you want your results to be decrypted upon find, you add the decrypt behavior.
So there you NEED the option to detach/unload behaviors because you might not want this functionality there at some point.

Models are just access to the database or provide wrapper methods. They don't have to be removed in order for the rest of the site to function as they do not alter the way other methods work.

loadModel is just a way to dynamically load models that are not automatically related. its totally fine to do that from controller actions where you need those models.